# Using network URL in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an image in which click is bind to open some url in other window. The image is like

```
<img id="ImgDPreview" src="../images/preview/thumbnail_pdf.jpg" style="border-width:0px;">
```

What below is a C# code snippet.

```
string PdfFilePath="\\\\192.23.8.19\\ArvinsPC\\MyFolders\\Original\\69a03d19-4b3d-41bc-9dcf-02982a1468df.pdf";
ImgDPreview.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return PreviewFiles('" + PdfFilePath + "');");
```

After running this, `ImgDPreview` is like

```
<img id="ImgDPreview" onclick="return PreviewFiles('\\192.23.8.19\ArvinsPC\MyFolders\Original\69a03d19-4b3d-41bc-9dcf-02982a1468df.pdf');" src="../images/preview/thumbnail_pdf.jpg" style="border-width:0px;">

function PreviewFiles(FilePath){
   //FilePath here becomes-->'\\192.23.8.19ArvinsPCMyFoldersOriginal69a03d19-4b3d-41bc-9dcf-02982a1468df.pdf'     
   window.open(FilePath);
}
```

The issue is on each step a backslash is being vanished from the URL. I know the javascript consider backslash as an escape character. But I need my URL unaltered. Is there any resolution for this.

URL and function names are fictional

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `192.23.8.19/ArvinsPC/MyFolders/Original/69a03d19-4b3d-41bc-9dcf-02982a1468df.pdf` is accessible from browser. You need to do the following

1. prepend the protocol to it to make it a complete URL
2. Remove `\\` from the URL
3. Replace `\` with `/`

Code

```
 function PreviewFiles(FilePath){
   FilePath = "https://" + FilePath.replace(/\\\\/g, "").replace(/\\/g, "/");
   window.open(FilePath);
 }
```

or as suggested by **@slyhuy**

```
window.open(FilePath.replace(/\\/gi, '/'));
```

I assumed that you are looking for `https`, you can replace it with the protocol you are using.

If the URL is not accessible from browser, you need to write a service on the server side to accept this `FilePath` from browser and return you the image.

Comment: It is a network path. I afraid I can add http protocol before that url string

Comment: @Arvin you need to convert it to the path that is accessible from browser.

Comment: This is correct, but @Arvin don't know how you attempt to tell him.

Comment: Who vote down this absolute correct answer?

Comment: I think @Arvin downvote due an answer misunderstanding

Comment: Please change

`window.open(FilePath);`
to
`window.open(FilePath.replace(/\\/gi, '/'));`

with // we no need add protocol, browser will auto detect.

Comment: @SLyHuy this replace was already done in line before

Comment: @gurvinder372 No I didn't down vote that.But if I convert that to a look alike HTTP url, what is the original http url is with some other domain. Any way thanks for the help. I got another HTTP url pointing the same file and using that

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude I know it is a wrong practice, but that was a public url. Any way I got an HTTP url and using that solved the issue

Comment: Is a public URI not URL. And is a windows-only URI, that's not compatible in web, almost is not the way that the web is concerned. Good luck!